# If I make a website design using WebFlow, then export it and edit functions, links with the backend etc outside, how can I redit the design?

Tags: java, html, css, hosting, webflow

I am using one of the templates on WebFlow to give me somewhere to start, and am going to create the website design first without functionality, then export that to html or Java.

With that design the web dev is going to implement functionality with the back end, functions, admin panel, payment protocols etc, after this is done it will be hosted.

my question is, if I want to edit the website later, I cannot just import it back into WebFlow correct? what would be the best editor, preferably visual, should I want to edit it?

Also, if we choose to instead host everything on WebFlow including the admin panel and backend, Database, if we choose later on to export to another host, are we able too? As I see that WebFlow says you are unable to export their CMS, is Webflow CMS basically a admin panel/backend that updates the front end?